# What are the reasons for this benchmark result?

Tags: loops, benchmarking, vectorization, julia

Two functions that convert a rgb image to a gray scale image:

```
function rgb2gray_loop{T<:FloatingPoint}(A::Array{T,3})
  r,c = size(A)
  gray = similar(A,r,c)
  for i = 1:r
    for j = 1:c
      @inbounds gray[i,j] = 0.299*A[i,j,1] + 0.587*A[i,j,2] + 0.114 *A[i,j,3]
    end
  end
  return gray
end
```

And:

```
function rgb2gray_vec{T<:FloatingPoint}(A::Array{T,3})
  gray = similar(A,size(A)[1:2]...)
  gray = 0.299*A[:,:,1] + 0.587*A[:,:,2] + 0.114 *A[:,:,3]
  return gray
end
```

The first one is using loops, while the second one uses vectorization.

When benchmarking them (with the Benchmark package) I get the following results for different sized input images (`f1` is the loop version, `f2` the vectorized version):

`A = rand(50,50,3)`:

```
| Row | Function | Average     | Relative | Replications |
|-----|----------|-------------|----------|--------------|
| 1   | "f1"     | 3.23746e-5  | 1.0      | 1000         |
| 2   | "f2"     | 0.000160214 | 4.94875  | 1000         |
```

`A = rand(500,500,3)`:

```
| Row | Function | Average    | Relative | Replications |
|-----|----------|------------|----------|--------------|
| 1   | "f1"     | 0.00783007 | 1.0      | 100          |
| 2   | "f2"     | 0.0153099  | 1.95527  | 100          |
```

`A = rand(5000,5000,3)`:

```
| Row | Function | Average  | Relative | Replications |
|-----|----------|----------|----------|--------------|
| 1   | "f1"     | 1.60534  | 2.56553  | 10           |
| 2   | "f2"     | 0.625734 | 1.0      | 10           |
```

I expected one function to be faster than the other (maybe f1 because of the inbounds macro).

But I can't explain, why the vectorized version gets faster for larger images.
Why is that?

Comment: I think the statement `gray = similar(A,size(A)[1:2]...)` in the vectorized version is unnecessary, the language will create the proper array size directly from the second statement. This doesn't explain why the vectorized version gets faster, though.

Comment: Off-topic, but you can say `convert(Array{Gray{Float64}}, A)` if you're `using Images`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer for the results is that multidimensional arrays in Julia are stored in column-major order. See [Julias Memory Order](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#access-arrays-in-memory-order-along-columns).

Fixed looped version, regarding column-major-order (inner and outer loop variables swapped):

```
function rgb2gray_loop{T<:FloatingPoint}(A::Array{T,3})
  r,c = size(A)
  gray = similar(A,r,c)
  for j = 1:c
    for i = 1:r
      @inbounds gray[i,j] = 0.299*A[i,j,1] + 0.587*A[i,j,2] + 0.114 *A[i,j,3]
    end
  end
  return gray
end
```

New results for `A = rand(5000,5000,3)`:

```
| Row | Function | Average  | Relative | Replications |
|-----|----------|----------|----------|--------------|
| 1   | "f1"     | 0.107275 | 1.0      | 10           |
| 2   | "f2"     | 0.646872 | 6.03004  | 10           |
```

And the results for smaller Arrays:

`A = rand(500,500,3)`:

```
| Row | Function | Average    | Relative | Replications |
|-----|----------|------------|----------|--------------|
| 1   | "f1"     | 0.00236405 | 1.0      | 100          |
| 2   | "f2"     | 0.0207249  | 8.76671  | 100          |
```

`A = rand(50,50,3)`:

```
| Row | Function | Average     | Relative | Replications |
|-----|----------|-------------|----------|--------------|
| 1   | "f1"     | 4.29321e-5  | 1.0      | 1000         |
| 2   | "f2"     | 0.000224518 | 5.22961  | 1000         |
```

Comment: Nice. Could you also try the `@simd` macro on your loops and see if it speeds it up any further?

Answer (score 1):

Just speculation because I don't know Julia-Lang:

I think the statement `gray = ...` in the vectorized form creates a new Array where all the calculated values are stored, while the old array is scrapped. In `f1` the values are overwritten in place, so no new memory allocation is needed. Memory allocation is quite expensive so the loop-version with in-place overwrites is faster for low numbers.

But memory allocation is usually a static overhead (allocation twice as much doesn't take twice as long) and the vectorized version is computing faster (maybe in parallel ?) so if the numbers get big enough the faster calculation makes more difference than the memory allocation.

Comment: In Julia, vectorized operations are typically slower than the elementwise ones since the latter ones produce less temporaries. The vectorized version here will create three temporary arrays and then sum them together, whereas the elementwise version doesn't need any extra temporaries and uses only a single loop.

Comment: @cfh This is what I thought - memory impact is more for vectorized. But on the other hand a vectorized version could be computed in parallel on 4 cores. And there might be a break-even-point, where 4-times CPU brings more benefit than the memory allocation costs. Did you test on a quad-core ?

Comment: I don't think these computations are automatically distributed over cores in Julia at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your results.

See this IJulia notebook: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/24c17478ae0f5562c449/raw/8d5d32c13209a6443c6d72b31e2459d70607d21b/rgb2gray.ipynb

The numbers I get are:

```
In [5]:

@time rgb2gray_loop(rand(50,50,3));
@time rgb2gray_vec(rand(50,50,3));

elapsed time: 7.591e-5 seconds (80344 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.000108785 seconds (241192 bytes allocated)

In [6]:

@time rgb2gray_loop(rand(500,500,3));
@time rgb2gray_vec(rand(500,500,3));

elapsed time: 0.021647914 seconds (8000344 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.012364489 seconds (24001192 bytes allocated)

In [7]:

@time rgb2gray_loop(rand(5000,5000,3));
@time rgb2gray_vec(rand(5000,5000,3));

elapsed time: 0.902367223 seconds (800000440 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 1.237281103 seconds (2400001592 bytes allocated, 7.61% gc time)
```

As expected, the looped version is faster for large inputs. Also note how the vectorized version allocated three times as much memory.

I also want to point out that the statement `gray = similar(A,size(A)[1:2]...)` is redundant and can be omitted.
Without this unnecessary allocation, the results for the largest problem are:

```
@time rgb2gray_loop(rand(5000,5000,3));
@time rgb2gray_vec(rand(5000,5000,3));

elapsed time: 0.953746863 seconds (800000488 bytes allocated, 3.06% gc time)
elapsed time: 1.203013639 seconds (2200001200 bytes allocated, 7.28% gc time)
```

So the memory usage went down, but the speed did not noticeably improve.

Comment: I can reproduce my results with @time.
I guess Falco is right and the results are related to some kind of parallelization on my machine....

Comment: @reschu: That doesn't sound right. First, Julia doesn't auto-parallelize. Also note that your given times for the looped version grow worse than linearly with the size of the problem: from the second to the third problem, it was 200x slower, although the problem size was only 100x larger. Something weird must be going on there.

Comment: Yes, you are right. And I found out what it is. Something I first read when starting with Julia: Column-major order. Swapping rows and columns in the nested loop leads to the expected results.

Comment: @reschu: That's interesting! Will you add an answer to describe what you did? I also might have to retract my statement that Julia doesn't auto-parallelize -- it uses OpenBLAS, and that can take advantage of multiple cores under certain circumstances. So it might be a combination of these two factors.